# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to force portrait splash screen?

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, screen-orientation

I need to force just the splash screen in portrati orientation, for all devices.

On Worklight, Phonegap or cordova, there is some configuration that i can use to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To lock the application's orientation in Android, open the `AndroidManifest.xml` file (located at yourProject\apps\yourApp\android\native) and add the following:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```

As for keeping the splash in portrait but the app in both portrait and landscape, this **is not the right approach** in my opinion.

Instead, you should create your splash image using [Google's 9patch approach](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) so that it would fit properly both portrait and landscape.

What you are asking for is not possible (in Worklight, or at all?) IMO.

Comment: @idan-adan I need to force just the splash screen. My AndroidManifest.xml has only one activity that is the name of my Worklight APP.

Comment: I found this link: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes that shows all sizes for splash screen, but i need to know the name of the images, I think if I create all sizes for splash screen my problem on landscape will not happen anymore. The problem is when the app starts on landscape mode the image of the splash get distorts. Worklight uses the name splash.9.png.

Comment: If you will properly create the splash image using 9patch it should fit all screens. Please read about 9patch; there can also be only 1 splash image, "splash.9.png".

Comment: I've used the 9patch to develop my splash screen, it's a great tool to make a splash screen.